# Setting the hostname for a container running in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to set the hostname in a container running inside Kubernetes, but Kubernetes appears to be overriding whatever I set at runtime.

I've tried both setting /etc/hostname in the docker image I'm having Kubernetes use, and including `echo "host.example.com > /etc/hostname"` in the CMD in the Dockerfile.

There appears to be a docker flag `-h` to set the hostname. Is there a way for me to specify in my replication controller that it should start the container with a special flag?

The container's Debian, if it helps.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

My previous answer was incorrect, edited with correct info

The `-h` flag for `docker run` will set the hostname of the container when you create it.

Test it out: `docker run -h test.example.com -it ubuntu /bin/bash`

The `docker start` command does not have the same `-h` or `--hostname` argument though. It doesn't seem possible to change the hostname of an existing container, just a new one from an image.

However w/r/t Kubernetes: There is an open [issue on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/4825) regarding how Kubernetes handles hostnames.  It does not seem like Kubernetes exposes docker's hostname setting directly, but you might be able to influence it via your pod name

Comment: If I attempt to use the `hostname` command I get the error `hostname: you must be root to change the host name`, even though this being in a container it's running as uid 0. I've tried modifying `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` as the page you linked to suggests, but the hostname remains what it was set to by Kubernetes. I notably can't run the `sudo service hostname restart` command from the page, but there is a `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh`. I can't use `restart`, as `argument 'restart' not supported`, and when I use `start` I get the same error as with the `hostname` command.

Comment: You are going to need to use sudo in front of the hostname command.  Even though the container itself is running as `uid:0` on the host's process tree, the services within the container have their own userspaces (At least that's how I think of it). Does `sudo hostname host.example.com` work?

Comment: Things are running under uid 0 in my container, so `sudo` shouldn't change anything. Regardless I installed sudo, and ran `sudo hostname -b webauth-kube.csh.rit.edu`. I got the error `hostname: you must be root to change the host name` again.

Comment: I doubt you can set the hostname in Kubernetes because of the pod thing; all containers will share the same network namespace.

Comment: Is there any way to lie to a process about the machine's hostname when it asks then? My exact issue is that Kerberos doesn't know its domain.

Comment: Ok I decided to fire up my docker stack again and reeducate myself... edited answer to reflect what I found. I learned a lot from this question which is awesome but also probably should have checked my answer before posting

Comment: can the -h option be added in the Dockerfile before the creation of the container?

Comment: doubtful, a Dockerfile is used to build an image that can be the base for many containers. Hostnames should uniquely identify containers... not images.

Comment: docker's  `run` command is a combination of `create` and `start`, so while the `-h` option cannot be used on `start`, it can be used on `create`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for changing the docker hostname after the container has been running or I can say to the existing container here are some steps

1. Run

   ```
   docker inspect -f '{{ .State.Pid }}' <existing_docker_hostname>
   ```

   Output will be a number <15580>
2. Run this command to login to the container

   ```
   nsenter --target 15580 --uts
   ```
3. Run this command to change the hostname

   ```
   hostname "node_js"
   ```

now exit the container and login again you will see the hostname has been changed.